# How can I confine text to the bounds of a SPAN element, including accents/combining characters?

Tags: html, css, unicode, zalgo

So, some smartass is putting [Zalgo Text](http://www.eeemo.net/) in their username.  I don't actually want to restrict users from having accents in their names, but text above/below their name can be difficult to read.  (note that this example actually renders pretty well here on the finished SO page, but in the editor it's another matter!)

```
Tͤ̔ͧ̇̍ͣh̥̼ͧͤͭͫ̇͋̿͟i̧̹̥̳̲͎ͨ̿̐̚s̰͕̫̥ ̳͚̳̟̫̭̯͊ͭ̅̏̊i̢͖̭̾ͦ̓͆s̗̹ ̸̬̙̯̫̓̊ͪͭͩ̿ś̰̱̥̖̈̌̆̿ī̥͔̽m̛̹̙̈́̾̊p̙̪̘̄̽̄͗ͦl͕̭̱͎̄͆ě̂͒͑̄ ̜͎̯͚̠̖̍͊̕s̱̞̺ͣ̓̓̒͜a͍ͫ͑͜m͍̙̠̻̲͍̜͒́̇̓͛̍̑p̪̩̪͙͍̥̆͗͝l͍̔̾ͨě̷̞̯̫̮̝̔̓͂̾̐̊ ͂̊̍̑ͨ͒̈́t͉̯̜̣̹̋̊̉́e̶̟̘̬ͫ̊̉̚ͅx̳̻͙̫̮̲͚ț̟͕́̌̚
This is a second example
```

Right now, the user name on my site is displayed in a simple `<span>`.  I'd like to apply a style to the span that effectively crops the text it contains to prevent it from spilling outside (above/below) the element.

Note that right now, behavior is pretty inconsistent -- sometimes the symbols "bleed into" the line below the user name, and sometimes they don't.  It might also vary from browser to browser.  I'd prefer a simple, cross-platform solution, if possible.

Comment: would this suit your needs? http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/9Lrsvc2d/

Comment: @web-tiki, that's it exactly.  If you want to leave it as an answer I'll accept it.  I knew *about* `inline-block` but it didn't occur to me that it was the missing link.  I had tried `overflow:hidden` but of course that doesn't mean anything for inline elements :-/

Comment: hi, did you solve your issue? Did my answer help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`overflow:hidden;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) property. You just need to set the display property of the span to inline-block :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/9Lrsvc2d/)**

*CSS :*

```
span{
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```